# How much damage would the industrial extraction of oil do to an uninhabited jungle island?

Tags: environment, natural-resources, ecology

**Note: I have done considerable research on this topic and have not yet found an answer that fits the specific conditions of my question. Since my question has unique conditions, (for example: The oil company does not want to spend any money on not damaging the environment, whereas most real companies do.), I think that it is both suited to worldbuilding (As the conditions are unique and fictitious.), and that Stack Exchange is an easier way of getting an answer than the alternative (Compiling a large amount of research from many sources, plus some educated speculation as well probably.) There is also no other SE site I could ask this on (Because of the speculative/fictional conditions, it would be very specific for Earth Science.SE or some other site.) If you agree, I would be grateful if you voted to re-open this question.**

My island is in the Indian Ocean. I'm not sure what size it'll be, but at least 10,000 square kilometers, maximum 40,000. It's covered in jungle and tropical savannah, and highly biodiverse. It contains species, including megafauna, not found anywhere else, but has no human habitation.

So, if a very very powerful oil company wanted to tap the abundant oil reserves, and planned to build a large oil drilling facility there, what damage would it do to the ecosystem?

The facility includes: Heavy equipment for extracting the oil, large (but cheap and portable) containers for the oil, accommodation for the workers, a runway for big cargo planes to transport it, an electric fence around the facility for keeping out dangerous wildlife, and a garage for reconnaissance vehicles (With the appropriate equipment to locate large oil deposits.) All the facilities will be as cheap as possible, provided that they do the job as profitably as possible.

The company will not be concerned about the damage to the ecosystem, so will extract the oil in the cheapest, most profitable way possible.

Comment: This is what happens every time an oil company set up an extraction plant. Where is the worldbuilding?

Comment: Depends on the exact geography of your island, money they are willing to spend to avoid damage, laws, and probably few other things.

Comment: I can't tell you about the exact geography right now without writing a paragraph,  but, as said, they don't care about the damage and no government is aware of their operations on the island.

Comment: That gets back to the "how is no government possibly unaware"?

Comment: There are a lot of risks and it's already well documented. You can find it if you type your own question title. Also, moving goods by air is one the least effective way to do it.

Comment: "*The oil company does not want to spend any money on not damaging the environment*".  Then you're guaranteed to get pollution.    The extent of the pollution depends on how sloppy the workers are, and how large the island is.

Comment: A Chinook can carry 9000 kg of cargo over a short distance, which is about 11.2 cubic meters of petroleum, about 70 barrels of oil. The average price of oil in 2017 averaged fifty-seven dollars a barrel, so the cargo is worth about four thousand dollars. A heavy lift helicopter can cost you a thousand or more per hour, so if your flight is more than two hours one way, you're losing money flying petroleum.

Comment: @RonJohn Yes, and the extent of it  is what I'm trying to find out in the question.

Comment: But no one can answer that question without seeing the specifics of what the oil company has built and how it operates.

Comment: @RonJohn Okay, I'll add that in - thanks for the help.